# Matrix multiplication subproblem graph vertex degree

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization

I am studying dynamic programming and in chapter 15.2 of the Cormen's **Introduction to Algorithms** one reads:

> For matrix-chain multiplication, if we were to draw the subproblem graph, it would have `O(n^2)` vertices and each vertex would have **degree at most `n - 1`**, giving a total of `O(n^3)` vertices and edges.

and when I draw a graph of `n = 4`, I get:

[image]

But, vertex `M[1, 4]` has degree 6 > 4 - 1. What I misunderstood?

Comment: Please include the particular graph algorithm you're using.  Citing an off-site resource by name is not proper treatment on Stack Overflow; we expect your question to be self-contained.

Comment: Most of all, I'm unclear how your `M[i, j]` notation relates to a linear matrix chain.

Comment: @Prune, `M[i, j]` is the minimum cost of parenthesising the matrix product `Ai ... Aj`.

Answer (score 1):

Solving a subproblem should give you a solution to the main problem, though possibly not the best one. So, a subproblem here is the computation of two products, not one. For the product `A1 A2 A3 A4` with `n=4` we have three, i.e. `n-1`, subproblems: (`A1`, `A2 A3 A4`), (`A1 A2`, `A3 A4`) and (`A1 A2 A3`, `A4`).

**Edit.** The book also reads:

> Thus, we can build an optimal solution to an instance of the matrix-chain multiplication problem by splitting the problem into two subproblems (optimally parenthesizing `Ai ... Ak` and `Ak+1 ... Aj`), ...

So, the subproblem is a computation of a single product, not two. It seems that either the book has inconsistency in the definition of a subproblem, or `n-1` bound is not correct, and should be `2(n-1)`.